# Malloc, free, and multiple pointers, how does it work?

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, free

I have multiple pointers pointing to dynamically allocated memory which was assigned using single malloc.

```cpp
int *p1, *p2;
p1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
p2 = &p1[5];
free(p2);
p1[5] = 3;
p1[6] = 5;
```

Now my question is what does 'free(p2)' statement would do? Will it free memory ahead p1[5]? Is it safe to use memory ahead p1[5](i.e. p1[6], p1[7] , . .)

Comment: "_Now my question is what does 'free(p2)' statement would do?_" Undefined behavior: the C++ standard doesn't define the behavior of such statement.

Comment: There are basically three options. It does nothing; it crashes the program immediately; or it corrupts the heap, leading the program to crash later down the line.

Comment: Sidenote: `malloc` and `free` have uses in low-level memory management routines and in the company of placement `new`, but for the most part they should be avoided in favour of [library containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), and `new`/`delete, usually in that order of preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You cannot predict the behavior of this function, as it is undefined behavior

From the reference:

> Deallocates the space previously allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `aligned_alloc`, (since C11) or `realloc()`.
>
> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the function does nothing.
>
> **The behavior is undefined if the value of `ptr` does not equal a value returned earlier by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, or `aligned_alloc()` (since C11).**
>
> —**`free`**, [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)

Emphasis mine: your use of `free` in this context would involve freeing from a pointer that was not obtained from the use of any of those functions; it was obtained by transforming the pointer that was obtained from `malloc`, and thus is not valid.

My best guess at what *might* happen is a segmentation fault; but that's up to your compiler, and not something you or I can guarantee.

So do not do this.

Answer (score 4):

Freeing a pointer that wasn't `malloc`/`calloc`ed is undefined behavior.
Some allocators such as glibc's can sometimes detect it and deterministically crash the program with a `free(): invalid pointer` error message, but technically you lose any and all guarantees about your program's behavior if you do it.